Window 10 -Mosquitto MQTT broker: client connection error
Mosquitto MQTT broker is host on PC a, ip address: 177.213.175.194 (example)
my mosquitto.conf
#default listener
listener 1818
protocol mqtt


use mqtt client to connect Mosquitto MQTT broker is successfully :
setting :

host : mqtt:// localhost
port:1818

however, using other laptop connect this MQTT broker
setting :

host : mqtt:// 177.213.175.194
port:1818

the result is failed and having the following pop up:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
how do i can successfully connect this MQTT broker in the PC?

Is mosquitto running as a service and did you restart it after changing the config file? Have you opened the port in the firewall?

In addition to the above 177.213.175.194 is a public IP (looks like it's owned by Telefônica Brasil) - please confirm if you are actually trying to connect via a public address, or if this was just an example and the real address is on a LAN (generally such an IP would start with 192., 10. or 172.). I would suggest testing over a LAN before attempting access over the internet (which generally requires more configuration, for example a port forward on your router firewall).
